# Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multicore, multiprocessing

This question is more fact finding and thought process than code oriented.

I have many compiled C++ programs that I need to run at different times and with different parameters. I'm looking at using Python multiprocessing to read a job from job queue (rabbitmq) and then feed that job to a C++ program to run (maybe subprocess). I was looking at the multiprocessing module because this will all run on dual Xeon server so I want to take full advantage of the multiprocessor ability of my server.

The Python program would be the central manager and would simply read jobs from the queue, spawn a process (or subprocess?) with the appropriate C++ program to run the job, get the results (subprocess stdout & stderr), feed that to a callback and put the process back in a queue of processes waiting for the next job to run.

First, does this sound like a valid strategy?

Second, are there any type of examples of something similar to this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get multiple C++ programs running at the same time, or must they run serially, with the next run's parameters depending on the output of the current run?

Comment: Typically I want multiple C++ programs running at the same time, with no dependence between one and another. Sometimes, a different C++ program will require a follow-up program to run serially after it has finished.

Answer (score 11):

> The Python program would be the
>   central manager and would simply read
>   jobs from the que, spawn a process (or
>   subprocess?) with the appropriate C++
>   program to run the job, get the
>   results (subprocess stdout & stderr),
>   feed that to a callback and put the
>   process back in a que of processes
>   waiting for the next job to run.

You don't need the `multiprocessing` module for this. The `multiprocessing` module is good for running *Python* functions as separate processes. To run a C++ program and read results from stdout, you'd only need the `subprocess` module. The queue could be a list, and your Python program would simply loop while the list is non-empty.

---

However, if you want to

1. spawn multiple worker processes
2. have them read from a common queue
3. use the arguments from the queue to
   spawn C++ programs (in parallel)
4. use the output of the C++ programs
   to put new items in the queue

then you could do it with `multiprocessing` like this:

**test.py**:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess
import shlex

def worker(q):
    while True:
        # Get an argument from the queue
        x=q.get()

        # You might change this to run your C++ program
        proc=subprocess.Popen(
            shlex.split('test2.py {x}'.format(x=x)),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out,err=proc.communicate()

        print('{name}: using argument {x} outputs {o}'.format(
            x=x,name=mp.current_process().name,o=out))

        q.task_done()

        # Put a new argument into the queue
        q.put(int(out))

def main():
    q=mp.JoinableQueue()

    # Put some initial values into the queue
    for t in range(1,3):
        q.put(t)

    # Create and start a pool of worker processes
    for i in range(3):
        p=mp.Process(target=worker, args=(q,))
        p.daemon=True
        p.start()
    q.join()
    print "Finished!"

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

**test2.py** (a simple substitute for your C++ program):

```
import time
import sys

x=int(sys.argv[1])
time.sleep(0.5)
print(x+3)
```

Running `test.py` might yield something like this:

```
Process-1: using argument 1 outputs 4
Process-3: using argument 3 outputs 6
Process-2: using argument 2 outputs 5
Process-3: using argument 6 outputs 9
Process-1: using argument 4 outputs 7
Process-2: using argument 5 outputs 8
Process-3: using argument 9 outputs 12
Process-1: using argument 7 outputs 10
Process-2: using argument 8 outputs 11
Process-1: using argument 10 outputs 13
```

Notice that the numbers in the right-hand column are fed back into the queue, and are (eventually) used as arguments to `test2.py` and show up as numbers in the left-hard column.

Answer (score 1):

> First, does this sound like a valid strategy?

Yes.

> Second, are there any type of examples of something similar to this?

[Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good strategy, but you don't need the `multiprocessing` module for it, but rather the `subprocess` module. `subprocess` is for running child processes from a Python program and interacting with them (stdio, stdout, pipes, etc.), while `multiprocessing` is more about distributing *Python code* to run in multiple processes to gain performance through parallelism.

Depending on the responsiveness strategy, you *may* also want to look at `threading` for launching subprocesses from a thread. This will allow you to wait on one subprocess while still being responsive on the queue to accept other jobs.